# WMP 12: Any way to save the sorted state of an auto playlist?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

My auto-playlists (smart playlists) are very long so I like to sort them by Album, which I can do by right clicking the Album column. Then they are nicely grouped by Album.

However, every time I start the playlist again it doesn't remember this setting, so I must do it again.

Anyone know a way to make it save this sort/grouping order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the auto playlist and select `Edit`. Then, use `[Click here to add criteria]` to add a `Sort by` rule. You can then further customize the rule to `Sort by Album Title Ascending order`. Click `OK` to save the changes.

Comment: Cool thanks I'll check it out when I get back to the computer

Comment: well that didn't do what I needed but my guess is nothing will... I need it grouped by album, sorting just makes it one big long messy list... but when you group by album, everything is nice and organized. Very important for live shows.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for misunderstanding. There's unfortunately not a `Group by` rule for auto playlists in WMP...